# Oracle query to get data between specific time

Tags: sql, oracle

We are trying to find out the transactions made in between 00 to 03 AM for  WHOLE YEAR.

Tried extract and to_date functions with many modification but unable to get the exact result.

Below Gives data just for current month even the date is not specified

```
and TXNDATE >= to_date('00:00:00', 'HH24:MI:SS')
and TXNDATE <= to_date('03:30:00','HH24:MI:SS')
```

Please assist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about just extracting the hour?

```
and extract(hour from TXNDATE) < 3
```

If you want to handle the time directly, strings might be the best approach:

```
to_char(txndate, 'HH24:MI:SS') >= '00:00:00' and
to_char(txndate, 'HH24:MI:SS') < '03:00:00'
```

If performance is an issue and you want to use an index, you can create an index incorporating `to_char(txndate, 'HH24:MI:SS')`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
WHERE to_char(tnxdate, 'HH24:MI:SS') between '00:00:00' and '03:30:00'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using 'EXTRACT' but you have to be careful about coding the edge conditions correctly. Here's an example:

```
WITH cteTxndates AS (SELECT TO_DATE('01-JAN-2018 00:00:00', 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') AS TXNDATE FROM DUAL UNION ALL  -- *
                     SELECT TO_DATE('01-JAN-2018 00:00:01', 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') AS TXNDATE FROM DUAL UNION ALL  -- *
                     SELECT TO_DATE('05-FEB-2018 00:01:01', 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') AS TXNDATE FROM DUAL UNION ALL  -- *
                     SELECT TO_DATE('10-MAR-2018 00:10:01', 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') AS TXNDATE FROM DUAL UNION ALL  -- *
                     SELECT TO_DATE('15-MAR-2018 01:00:01', 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') AS TXNDATE FROM DUAL UNION ALL  -- *
                     SELECT TO_DATE('20-APR-2018 10:00:01', 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') AS TXNDATE FROM DUAL UNION ALL  -- 
                     SELECT TO_DATE('25-MAY-2018 02:00:01', 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') AS TXNDATE FROM DUAL UNION ALL  -- *
                     SELECT TO_DATE('30-JUN-2018 03:00:01', 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') AS TXNDATE FROM DUAL UNION ALL  -- *
                     SELECT TO_DATE('02-JUL-2018 10:00:01', 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') AS TXNDATE FROM DUAL UNION ALL  -- 
                     SELECT TO_DATE('20-AUG-2018 01:00:01', 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') AS TXNDATE FROM DUAL UNION ALL  -- *
                     SELECT TO_DATE('03-SEP-2018 02:30:01', 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') AS TXNDATE FROM DUAL UNION ALL  -- *
                     SELECT TO_DATE('30-OCT-2018 03:30:00', 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') AS TXNDATE FROM DUAL UNION ALL  -- *
                     SELECT TO_DATE('30-OCT-2018 03:30:01', 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') AS TXNDATE FROM DUAL UNION ALL  -- 
                     SELECT TO_DATE('04-NOV-2018 02:22:01', 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') AS TXNDATE FROM DUAL UNION ALL  -- *
                     SELECT TO_DATE('14-DEC-2018 01:11:01', 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') AS TXNDATE FROM DUAL),          -- *
     cteDatefields AS (SELECT TXNDATE,
                              EXTRACT(HOUR FROM CAST(TXNDATE AS TIMESTAMP)) AS XHOUR,
                              EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM CAST(TXNDATE AS TIMESTAMP)) AS XMINUTE,
                              EXTRACT(SECOND FROM CAST(TXNDATE AS TIMESTAMP)) AS XSECOND
                         FROM cteTxndates)
SELECT *
  FROM cteDatefields
  WHERE XHOUR >= 0 AND
        ( XHOUR < 3 OR
         (XHOUR = 3 AND XMINUTE < 30) OR
         (XHOUR = 3 AND XMINUTE = 30 AND XSECOND = 0));
```

[dbfiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=24ca62c42c7ccb89397db606ddb2c9c4)